# Rails Scoped has many through has many with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through, has-many

I have a model with a scoped has many. I would like to chain a has many through onto that:

```rb
 class X < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ys, {foreign_key: :y_id} do
    def for_z(z)
      where("boolean_flag = #{z.boolean_flag}")  
    end

  has_many :bs, through: :ys # but I want to get only the bs for ys.for_z(z)
  end
```

A `y` here belongs_to  a `b`

so in the end I'd like to call :

`something.xs.ys.for(z).bs`

right now I can still do

`something.xs.ys.for(z).map {|y| y.b}`

but I'd like to wire up the association correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually define a second association:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :issues
  has_many :open_issues,
    -> { where(status: 'open') },
    class_name: 'Issue'
    
  has_many :assignees, through: :open_issues
end
```

A `has_many through:` association just takes the name of another association that it joins through. You cannot define an association that goes through an [association extension](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) which you are incorrectly referring to as a scope.

A scope is really just a class method which can be called on any relation (since it proxies to the class) while association extensions can only be called on [*association proxies*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html).

If you want to actually create [a scoped association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many), you need to pass a callable such as a lambda.

```
has_many :open_issues,
  -> { where(status: 'open') },
  class_name: 'Issue'
```

This really just applies a set of filters directly to the association itself.

```
something.xs.ys.for(z).bs
```

Is not actually compatible with how associations actually work in Rails. Associations are not callable on relations or association proxy objects - only on records themselves.

Comment: Wow I'm starstruck!  Despite multiple instances in the docs indicating I could, I could not figure out how to pass an argument to a scoped association and in this case my for_z scope requires an argument to be passed. Therefor i was left to use the `def for_z` strategy which accepted an argument. Would you be under the impression that I should be able to pass an arg to my scoped association?

Comment: No, you can't pass arguments to the lambda as their is no way to pass that argument when you use includes, joins and eager_load.